# Getting error while configuring Gitlab with Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, redis, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to configure Azure redis cache premium(cluster mode enabled) with Gitlab Version 13.8.1.
I am getting below error , what might be he issue here:

```
**Redis::CommandError (CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot):**

lib/gitlab/instrumentation/redis_interceptor.rb:15:in `call'
app/models/active_session.rb:111:in `block in destroy_sessions'
lib/gitlab/instrumentation/redis_cluster_validator.rb:74:in `allow_cross_slot_commands'
app/models/active_session.rb:110:in `destroy_sessions'
app/models/active_session.rb:101:in `block in destroy_with_rack_session_id'
lib/gitlab/redis/wrapper.rb:18:in `block in with'
lib/gitlab/redis/wrapper.rb:18:in `with'
app/models/active_session.rb:100:in `destroy_with_rack_session_id'
config/initializers/warden.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:86:in `destroy'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:482:in `set_current_admin'
lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:473:in `set_session_storage'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:73:in `with_locale'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:79:in `with_user_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:467:in `set_locale'
lib/gitlab/error_tracking.rb:52:in `with_context'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:532:in `sentry_context'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:460:in `block in set_current_context'
lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:56:in `block in use'
```

Comment: [This article should be useful to you](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-crossslot-keys-error-redis/), if you have any progress, pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab doesnt support Redis with clustering enable, if you are using Azure Redis cahce premium then you can keep shard count to 0 , then it should work.